# Compartilhar PDF

Tags: android

Tenho uma aplicação que gera um pdf a partir de um conteúdo interno.

Preciso compartilhar este `pdf`, e para isso, faço da seguinte forma:

```
 final String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
 final Uri arquivo = Uri.parse( filePath);
 final Intent _intent = new Intent();
            _intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            _intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,  arquivo);
            _intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  "Meu  PDF");
            _intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,   "Meu pdf");

            _intent.setType("application/pdf");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(_intent, "Compartilhar"));
```

Sendo a variável `arquivo` uma `Uri`, com o caminho que do arquivo, que é gerado ao abrir a tela.

A intent é chamada após o click do usuário.

Quando tento enviar por email, o arquivo não é anexado.

Exibe uma Toast dizendo que não é possível anexar um arquivo vazio.

Mas quando vou até a pasta, ele abre normalmente!

Como faço para conseguir compartilhar por email este pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro ocorre devido a forma em que se pega a Uri do arquivo:

```
 final String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
 final Uri arquivo = Uri.parse( filePath);
```

Para arquivos internos deve se usar `Uri.fromFile`.

Exemplo:

```
 final Uri arquivo = Uri.fromFile(file);
```